# Can we have class level variables or state in spring configuration for bean creation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Do we really need class-level variables here?
Another cleaner way is to create a new object only when asked

Example :
Approach 1

/ **
Required imports relevant to spring boot;
**/

```
 @Configuration
 class MyConfig {
     private MyBean myBean = new MyBean()
     private SettingsService settingsService;
     private ConnectionConfig conConf;

     @Bean
     public MyBean myBean() {
         return this.settingsService()
             .fetchConnectionConf()
             .createBean().getMyBean();
     }

     private void settingsService() {
         settingsService = SettingsService.getInstance()
     }

     private fetchConnectionConf() {
         this.conConf = settingsService.getConnectionConfByTag("myService");

     }

     private void createBean() {
         bean.setProp(this.conConf.get("Prop1"));
         bean.setProp(this.conConf.get("Prop2"));
         return this;
     }

     private MyBean getMyBean() {
         return this.myBean()
     }

 }
```

Approach 2

/**
All necessary imports from spring boot etc.
**/

```
 @Configuration
 class MyConfig {
     @Bean
     public MyBean myBean() {
         final MyBean myBean = new MyBean()
         final SettingsService settingsService = SettingsService.getInstance();
         final ConnectionConfig conConf = settingsService.getConnectionConfByTag("myService");
         bean.setProp(this.conConf.get("Prop1"));
         bean.setProp(this.conConf.get("Prop2"));
         return myBean;
     }

 }
```

Which one to use and why? Approach one uses so-called fluent API but I think it is not needed at all.

Comment: Neither makes any sense as the first doesn’t compile and the neither has an `@Bean` annotation. But generally speaking, having spring decide when to create beans is exactly what you want - creating a single instance and returning the from an `@Bean` method is going to lead to weird and wonderful behaviour. Similarly if your bean has dependencies on other beans you’re going to quickly dig yourself a very deep hole.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have updated the code for clarity ..in my opinion, Approach 1 is not right as it has an unnecessary shared state and it has a chained private method which does not make sense, and also it might create a cycle as it relied on ordered call to methods
This is an example from some old bad code..we all see such code and ignore unfortunately instead of critically thinking only because it works :)

Comment: I have to say I’ve personally never seen anything like this code - I have no idea why someone would write it. It seems to hand crank Spring features such as configuration and subvert Spring fundamentals such as bean life cycles. (Also, it still won’t compile)